# ¿Cómo puedo sustituir una cadena en uno o muchos ficheros?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, zsh, procesamiento-de-texto

Sustituir cadenas en ficheros en base a ciertos criterios de búsqueda es una tarea común. ¿Cómo puedo...

1. sustituir la cadena `foo` con `bar` en todos los ficheros del directorio actual?
2. hacer lo mismo de forma recursiva en los subdirectorios?
3. sustituir solo si el nombre del fichero coincide con alguna otra cadena?
4. sustituir solo si la cadena se encuentra en un contexto determinado?
5. sustituir si la cadena está en un número de línea determinado?
6. sustituir múltiples cadenas con un mismo reemplazo?
7. sustituir múltiples cadenas con distintos reemplazos?

<sub>Esta es una adaptación de la pregunta en Unix & Linux [How can I replace a string in a file(s)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112023/40596) destinada a servir como canónica.</sub>

Comment: Traducido tras debatirlo hace un tiempo en Meta: [¿Es pertinente traducir la pregunta canónica “¿Cómo puedo sustituir una cadena en un fichero?” en una sola pregunta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3366/83)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Sustituir la cadena `foo` con `bar` en todos los ficheros del directorio actual

Este es el caso cuando tú *sabes* que el directorio contiene únicamente ficheros regulares y que quieres procesar todos los ficheros no ocultos. Si este no es el caso, utiliza las soluciones del punto 2.

Todas las soluciones en esta respuesta asumen GNU `sed`. Si usas FreeBSD o OS/X, sustituye `-i` por `-i ''`. Además, ten en cuenta que el uso del modificador `-i` tiene [implicaciones de seguridad](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-utils/2013-09/msg00000.html) para el filesystem y no se recomienda en ningún script que tengas en mente distribuir de alguna forma.

```
sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' *
perl -i -pe 's/foo/bar/g' ./*
```

([la solución en `perl` fallará para nombres de fichero terminados en `|` o espacio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170013/22565)).

Si estás utilizando zsh:

```
sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' **/*(D.)
```

(puede fallar si la lista de ficheros es demasiado grande, usa `zargs` como posible solución).

Bash no puede revisar directamente si los ficheros son regulares. Se necesita un bucle (las llaves impiden definit las opciones globalmente):

```
( shopt -s globstar dotglob;
    for file in **; do
        if [[ -f $file ]] && [[ -w $file ]]; then
            sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' "$file"
        fi
    done
)
```

Los ficheros se seleccionan cuando son realmente ficheros (`-f`) y se pueden escribir (`-w`).

### 2. Sustituir la cadena `foo` con `bar` en todos los ficheros del directorio actual y sus subdirectorios

Esto se realiza en todos los ficheros regulares (**incluyendo los ocultos**) en este directorio y sus subdirectorios

```
    find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
```

### 3. Sustituir la cadena `foo` con `bar` solo si el nombre del fichero coincide con alguna otra cadena / tiene una extensión determinada / es de un tipo determinado, etc

- No recursivo, solamente ficheros en este directorio:

  ```
  sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' *baz*    ## todos los ficheros cuyo nombre contiene baz
  sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' *.baz    ## todos los ficheros cuyo nombre termina en .baz
  ```
- Recursivo, ficheros regulares en este directorio y sus subdirectorios:

  ```
  find . -type f -name "*baz*" -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
  ```

  Si usas Bash (el paréntesis evita asignar las opciones globalmente):

  ```
  ( shopt -s globstar dotglob
      sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' **baz*
      sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' **.baz
  )
  ```

  Si usas zsh:

  ```
  sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' **/*baz*(D.)
  sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' **/*.baz(D.)
  ```

`--` sirve para decirle a `sed` que no se van a dar más opciones en la línea de comandos. Esto es útil para protegerse ante nombres de fichero que empiezan por `-`.

- Si el fichero es de un tipo determinado, por ejemplo, ejecutable (lee `man find` para ver otras opciones):

  ```
  find . -type f -executable -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
  ```

  `zsh`:

  ```
  sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' **/*(D*)
  ```

---

trabajo en proceso

Comment: Usar la expansion del shell como en `sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' *` incluye directorios, por lo tanto devuelve un código de error en los casos en que los haya. Programas que ven el código de salida (como make) pueden tener problemas. Es conveniente usar, por ejemplo, find. En GNU: `find . -maxdepth 1 -a -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g'`.