# Reemplazar parte de texto con Script

Tags: bash

Estoy empezando a programar y tengo una duda, tengo un montón de .txt a los cuales le he puesto una misma extensión en una línea, quiero cambiar esa palabra en cada uno de los .txt por los de una lista, no se muy bien como recorrer la lista para que vaya cogiendo las líneas, me gustaría hacerlo en bash no se si podreis ayudarme.

He probado algo así:

```
for i in *txt
sed -i "s/texto_a_reemplazar/$lista/" *.txt
done
```

Gracias por adelantado

Saludos,

---

Gracias por las respuestas, he estado probando esta solución a mi caso y os comento cosas:

- La lista la tengo en un archivo .txt que se llama "hostname.txt"
- Mi intención es hacerlo sencillo sustituyendo una palabra que está en todos los archivos, por los que están en la lista. He intentado hacerlo de esta manera:

  ```
  lista=$(cat hostname.txt)

  sed "/palabra_a_sustituir/$lista/g *.cfg
  ```

No se si me falta alguna cosa más, la verdad es que estoy leyendo pero no se si me vale para este caso.

Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas.

Comment: @Pikoh "probar" y "sed -i" nunca deberían ir en la misma frase :) Si eso, mejor usar `sed -i.bak` para que se haga una copia de seguridad.

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir algunos ejemplos de archivos de entrada y cómo quedarían sus respectivos archivos de salida? No me queda completamente claro lo que quieres lograr con la lista.

Comment: ¿Le pusiste esa instrucción con `sed ` tal cual la pegaste o tuviste un pequeño error al pegarlo? Porque `sed` sustituye con la orden `sed 's/pal1/pal2/g'`, nótese la letra 's'.

Comment: No sé cómo sean los datos de tu archivo hostname.txt, así que trataré de hacer lo posible en un update a mi respuesta.

Comment: Efectivamente falta la "s". el archivo hostname.txt tiene hostname de equipos en una columna.

Comment: También cuida lo de la comilla faltante en el comando de sed. Por cierto, ya actualicé (hasta el final) mi respuesta. Cualquier duda, no dudes en comentar por ahí.

Answer (score 0):

No entendí muy bien la parte de la lista que va a reemplazar a la cadena. Pero trataré de dejar en general un proceso que espero ayude.

```
#!/bin/bash

ruta="."
separador=","
texto_a_reemplazar="texto_a_reemplazar"

declare -a lista
lista=(
    texto1
    texto2
    texto3
    )
#Esto es lo que yo entiendo por "lista"

lista_a_cadena="$(
    IFS="$separador"
    printf "${lista[*]}"
)"
# ^^^^ esto te crea la variable lista_a_cadena como una cadena de la forma "texto1,texto2,texto3"
#      puedes cambiar el separador cambiando el valor del IFS

sed "s/$texto_a_reemplazar/$lista_a_cadena/g" $ruta/*.txt
#               El bucle "for" no es  necesario    ^^^^
#               cuando podrías hacer un pathname expansion
```

El resultado obtenido es algo de este estilo.

```
$ ./reemplazar
texto1,texto2,texto3:texto fijo
texto1,texto2,texto3:texto fijo
texto1,texto2,texto3:texto fijo
```

Puesto que tenía tres archivos que contenían la cadena `texto_a_reemplazar:texto fijo`

Para probar si los cambios son como los quieres, quita el parametro `-i` de `sed`, justo como yo lo hice.

En el [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/187445/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-sustituir-una-cadena-en-uno-o-muchos-ficheros) que compartió @fedorqui vienen más ejemplos, y bien explicados, de como reemplazar texto en varios archivos.

Si quieres información sobre el pathname expansion (y demás expansiones) puedes consultar el manual de bash `man 1 bash` en la sección de `EXPANSION`

Leer los manuales te va a ser de gran utilidad si estás aprendiendo a programar scripts en bash.

Para buscar la parte de expansiones puedes utilizar una expresión regular en tu paginador del manual (es común que sea el programa `less`). Para ello necesitarás poner esto cuando se abra el manual.

```
/^EXPANSION$
```

Y el paginador te llevará hasta esa coincidencia.

### Update 1

Suponiendo que tu archivo hostname.txt tiene un texto con el siguiente formato:

```
host1
host2
host3
```

Y que quieres sustituir esa lista en archivos que tienen esta estructura:

```
palabra1:palabra_a_sustituir:palabra3
```

Se me ocurre lo siguiente.

```
#!/bin/bash

carpeta="./archivos"  # En esta carpeta están tus archivos.
separador=","

declare -a lista
lista=($(cat hostname.txt))

sed "s/palabra_a_sustituir/$(echo ${lista[@]})/g" $carpeta/*  # Versión 1
sed "s/palabra_a_sustituir/$(IFS="$separador"; echo "${lista[*]}")/g" archivos/*  # Versión 2
```

La versión 1 te va a arrojar una salida de este tipo por cada coincidencia en los archivos en la carpeta.

```
palabra1:host1 host2 host3:palabra3
```

La versión 2 te va a arrojar una salida así por cada coincidencia.

```
palabra1:host1,host2,host3:palabra3
```

Comment: la idea de votar para cerrar como duplicado es que el conocimiento se concentre en una única pregunta. Tu respuesta es interesante, pero probablemente quede olvidada cuando se cierre esta pregunta...