# Cambiar el contenido de un valor de una línea en concreto shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, shell-script

necesitaría reemplazar un valor en concreto en una línea concreta en shell script.
En el fichero llamado 'usuarios.bd' tengo varias ocurrencias tales como : '12,15,19,15,14,0
'
Lo que yo quiero es cambiar ese 0 por un 1 pero que sólo sea en esa línea en concreto
En el script que os dejo abajo en el for voy recorriendo línea a línea y si entra en el if querría decir que es la línea que quiero y ahí es cuando procedería a sustituir.

```
contadorlineas=0
for line in $(cat usuarios.bd); #buscamos el id del usuario para ñadirle una reserva 
do
    echo "$line" > linea.txt
    idlinea="$(cut -d"," -f 1 linea.txt)"
    ((contadorlineas++))
    numprest="$(cut -d"," -f 6 linea.txt)"
    if [[ "$idlinea" -eq "$idusuario" ]]; then
        echo $line | sed s/0/1/g 
        lineaaborrar=$contadorlineas
        sed -i ''$lineaaborrar'd' usuarios.bd
        echo $line >> usuarios.bd
    fi
done
```

Como podéis comprobar he intentado utilizar el sed pero sin éxito alguno.
Gracias de antemano...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que haces con `sed` es únicamente modificar el texto que le llega por el *stdin* desde el *stdout* del `echo`, y no modificar el archivo.

Si quieres modificar esa línea, utiliza el número de línea que obtienes de tu variable `contadorlineas` en el comando `sed`.

```
sed -i "${contadorlineas}s/0/1/" usuarios.bd
```

Yo recomendaría el uso de `awk` porque nada me asegura que sólo vayas a encontrar un único "0" en esa línea, en cambio, si lo ves por campos separados por comas, podrías cambiar específicamente el sexto campo condicionándolo según su contenido y el número de línea.

```
awk -i inplace \
-F , \
-v linea=$contadorlineas \
-v busq=0 \
-v remp=1 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{
    if(NR==linea && $6==busq)
        $6=remp;
    print $0
}' usuarios.bd
```

en donde `-i inplace` es un nuevo aditamento en versiones de GNU awk 4.1.0+ y puede modificar el archivo que se pasa como parámetro (en este caso, "usuarios.bd"), `-F ,` establece el delimitador como coma y en parámetro `-v` crea variables y la pasa dentro del script de `awk`.

Las variables dentro que creo son `linea`, para el numero de linea a buscar, `busq` para buscar esa cadena a reemplazar y `remp` que es lo que reemplazará el valor de `busq`

Antes de probar las modificaciones dentro del archivo, pide que sólo te los muestre, ya sea que tomes la opción de `sed` o de `awk`, eliminando el parámetro de modificar en el mismo archivo, el `-i` de `sed` o el `-i inplace` de la versión moderna de `gawk`.

O, en pocas palabras, todo tu script lo podrías reconstruir en términos de `awk`. Esto también en parte a que haces uso de muchas utilidades de más, saturando tu script de programas para hacer algo "sencillo".

Por ejemplo, si tienes la variable `idusuario` con el valor de 2, podrías hacer algo por el estilo para buscar sobre ese id y el sexto campo de un archivo separado por comas.

```
idusuario=2
awk -F , \
-v busq=0 \
-v idusuario="$idusuario" \
-v remp=1 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{
    if($1==idusuario && $6==busq) 
        $6=remp;
    print $0;
}' usuarios.bd
```

Y si resultó como esperabas, ya podrías agregarle el parámetro `-i inplace`

Answer (score 2):

No te hace falta ningun shell script aquí, lo puedes hacer directamente con un solo comando `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak "/^$usuario,/{s/0/1/g }" usuarios.bd
```

El `/foo/{bar}` quiere decir "haz bar solo si la linea contiene `foo`". Entonces, aquí, solo se hará la substitución si la línea empieza (`^`) con el valor de la variable `$usuario` seguida de una coma.  El `-i` te permite modificar el fichero original, y el `-i.bak` te creerá un `usuarios.bd.bak` con el contenido original antes del cambio.

Entonces, no te hace falta contar las líneas, puedes ir directamente a buscar el usuario. En todo caso, tu script era mucho más complejo que necesario, mismo si haría falta. Esto hace la misma tarea que tu script de manera mas eficaz:

```
idusuario="2" 
while read linea; do
  if [[ $linea =~ ^${idusuario}, ]]; then
    linea=$(sed 's/0/1/g' <<<$linea)
  fi
  printf '%s\n' "$linea"
done < usuarios.bd > usuarios.corregido.bd
```

Comment: Por cierto, traduje tu pregunta canónica de U&L en [¿Cómo puedo sustituir una cadena en uno o muchos ficheros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/187445/83). Esta pregunta podría ser candidata a duplicada de la canónica.

Comment: @fedorqui ah, bien! No se si es realmente duplicado ya que aquí Marco y yo hemos adaptado las soluciones a este caso especifico. Pero tampoco me molestara si crees que es mejor cerrarla. Tu mateix :).