# Como cambiar determinadas palabras de un archivo de texto para un script

Tags: linux, bash, script

estoy aprendiendo a usar bash y tengo una duda para cambiar x palabra dentro de un archivo de texto.Por ejemplo hice este para cambiar el nombre de mi equipo

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Ingrese el nombre del equipo: " nombreEquipo
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname $nombreEquipo.dominio.local
```

Ahora no se como encarar para cambiar X palabra dentro de un archivo de texto grande, por ejemplo
dentro de /etc/hosts cambiar lxtest01 por $nombreEquipo sin tocar lo demas

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       lxtest01

#The following lines are desiable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Gracais de antemano

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo sustituir una cadena en uno o muchos ficheros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/187445/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-sustituir-una-cadena-en-uno-o-muchos-ficheros)

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi propuesta de solución, si hay dudas pregunta.

```
$ cat cambianombre.sh 

#! /bin/bash

# Preguntamos al usuario por el nombre anterior ($nombre_ant)
read -p "Ingrese nombre a cambiar: " nombre_ant

# Preguntamos al usuario por el nuevo nombre ($nombre_nue)
read -p "Ingrese nuevo nombre: " nombre_nue

# Como voy a hacer el reemplazo de un nombre por el otro
# con sed -i, que podría borrar el contenido del archivo que estamos
# modificado si $nombre_ant no existiera primero compruebo
# la existencia del nombre que ha dado el usuario y si
# existe procedo a cambiarlo por el nuevo nombre.

# Para esta prueba he usado un archivo llamado user_fake.

if grep $nombre_ant user_fake -q # Si existe $nombre_ant en user_fake... 
    then
        sed -i "s|$nombre_ant|$nombre_nue|g" user_fake # Sustituye nombre_ant por nombre_nue (utilizo | en lugar de / por las variables)
        echo "Cambiado $nombre_ant por $nombre_nue ..." # Mensaje informativo.
    else
        echo "El nombre anterior $nombre_ant no existe." # Mensaje infirmativo si el nombre original no existe en user_fake
        exit # Finaliza script (Sin cambios)
fi


$
```

Otra alternativa para hacer más ágil el script es cambiar la primera línea donde se le pregunta al usuario por el nombre anterior que queremos modificar por esta otra línea:

```
nombre_ant=$1
```

y el resto igual.

Con **nombre_ant=$1** le damos a nombre_ant el valor de la variable de posición $1 que es primer argumento que le podemos dar al script al ejecutarlo, haciéndolo así podríamos ejecutar el script de esta forma:

./cambianombre.sh nombre_anterior

De esta forma pasamos nombre_anterior como argumento y el script ya se inicia sabiendo a que nombre nos estamos refiriendo.

Comment: muchas gracias!!